# How to add a Git repo as an artifact to a build pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, build-pipeline, artifacts, repository

Coming off of the comments (and recommendations) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68538088), I'm trying to add a repo as an artifact to a build pipeline.

Apparently it's possible for a [release pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops-2020), but I'm not finding guidance for doing the same in a build pipeline. There don't seem to be any related tasks or configurations in the UI.

Is it possible to do this in Azure DevOps Server 2020? (I did find [this answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9372), but the proposed solution seems a bit complex for my needs.)